# Associating Views with Quick Links

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, promoted-links, quick-links

I am reasonably new to the modern interface of SharePoint and am looking to customise the Quick Links in the way I used to use Promoted Links.

In the promoted link I use to be able to set the address for a folder to display a particular view when the user browsed.  Is it possible to replicate this with the quick link?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using quick links web part. You can set the address of folder to quick link.

Check below official documentation for more information on quick links web part:

[Use Quick Links Web Part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-quick-links-web-part-e1df7561-209d-4362-96d4-469f85ab2a82)